# Expose WCF service for derived class with same name in C#

Tags: wcf, web-services

I want to expose as WCF service two set of classes that have the same name. However, when I add the service reference, it only returns one set of the class.

```
[ServiceContract(Name = "Service1")]
    [XmlSerializerFormat]
    public interface IService1
    {               

        [OperationContract]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(S1.Retangle))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(S1.Square))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(S2.Retangle))]
        [ServiceKnownType(typeof(S2.Square))]   
        string GetShape(Shape shape);

    }

    //All types are only example
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]   
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute()]
    public abstract class Shape
    {               
        public int Width { get; set; }

        public int Height { get; set; }

        public string TypeName { get; set; }
    }

    namespace S1
    {

        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute()]
        public class Retangle : Shape
        { }

        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute()]
        public class Square : Shape
        { }
    }

    namespace S2
    {

        //[DataContract]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "Namespace=http://tempuri.org/S2")]  //can be changed
        public class Retangle : Shape
        {   }

        //[DataContract]
        [System.SerializableAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "Namespace=http://tempuri.org/S2")] //can be changed
        public class Square : Shape
        {    }
    }
```

Any idea would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WCF will generate your objects in its own namespace for use client side but your not forced to use these - you can equally well use your own original objects in the namespaces they were defined by either:
1. Compiling them in a dll and linking to that for both client and sever.
2. If you dont want overhead of shared dll just compile them directly into both server and client.
In the generated proxy code you just need to replace the WCF namespace tags with your own org namespaces so they resolve to your objects and the client side WCF generated ones are ignored.

Comment: For interoperability, the WCF service operations are published via WSDL not via binary code. Thus, its clients will retrieve the contract using standard document, like WSDL.